# Unable to connect to Tomcat server with URL

Tags: java, tomcat

I can connect to my tomcat7 server using IP address but when I replace IP Address with my URL, I'm unable to connect to the host.

**Error Message displayed:**

> This web page is not available

ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
The website may be down or your network may not be properly configured.

Comment: Error message displayed:This web page is not available

ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: Please edit your question to add the error message.

Comment: You need to provide more info: What operating system are you on? What does your URL ping to? What do your logs say? If I had to take a guess your URL is not correct and you have a context path problem.

Comment: no not like that im using dreamhost for hosting.I choosed an option Cloaking then i removed that.May be it is taking time remove the Cloaking option.

Comment: thank you the issue resolved

Answer (score 0):

Try add pair `host_ip host_name` to host's file in your compruter.